# Electrostatic: do Electrons really go away?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electrons, charge

So imagine the classic science experiment where you take an empty aluminium can and a rubber bar that you charge with fur.

At first, that can is electrically neutral.

Two different cases now that I want to discuss:

1. If I put the can on a desk made out of wood, the can will be attracted by my charged rubber bar due to influence. So the electrons in my rubber bar push away the electrons being in the can as far away as possible (the other side) and so the rubber bar only "sees" the protons.
2. If I put the can on a desk made out of a metal which is grounded, what happens then? Still influence? Or is the electrically neutral can now positive due to electrons escaping to ground?

Would love to hear some thoughts.
Best regards

Comment: What makes you think the can would become neutral in the second case and not simply the first case happening, except as far away as possible means into ground, so there is a positive charge left in the can?

Comment: Well I assume that at the beginning, the can is electrically neutral. In the first case, the can is, in my opinion, not positively charged. Its still neutral. I think there is some polarization going on, so one side of the can has all the electrons, the other side of the can all the protons. Because the distance between the electrons in my rubber bar and the protons in my can is less than the distance between the electrons in the rubber bar and the electrons in the can, there is some attraction.
So what I get from your answer is basically the same, the electrons are going away. Am I wrong ?

Comment: A very, very small fraction of the electrons are moving. There's no part of the conductor that's made entirely of naked nuclei, nor is there even a macroscopic part of the conductor made mostly of ions missing one or more electron.